# Chart.js 4.2.1 with .net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, chart.js

I have a .net MVC project and I am working on integrating Chart.js library into my project. I am using Bundling to server all js files to browser in my project.
To add ChartJS 4.2.1 to my project in similar way, I downloaded js content from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.2.1/chart.js' and put it in a Chart-4.2.1.js file in my scripts directory. When I try to add this js file to my bundle, then bundle is throwing error without any details about what is wrong in js file. Can someone help me if there are any dependencies for this js file that I need to load to get rid of errors.

Comment: I believe import tag at the start of the script might be the core of the problem, as I have not seen that in any other js that we are using.

Comment: I don't know your environment, but you may try the umd version `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.2.1/chart.umd.js`, which is used to be included with a standard script tag and defines a global `Chart` object; the one you're using is for [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).